# Way to list all procedures in a Tcl file

Tags: tcl, expect

Is there any way to list all the procedures(proc) in a myFile.tcl using another tcl file or in the same file.

Comment: Do you want the proc names, or do you need to see the arg list and/or the proc body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[info procs]` before and after sourcing the file in question and compare the results to determine which procs were added.  For example:

```
proc diff {before after} {
    set result [list]
    foreach name $before {
        set procs($name) 1
    }
    foreach name $after {
        if { ![info exists procs($name)] } {
            lappend result $name
        }
    }
    return [lsort $result]
}

set __before [info procs]
source myFile.tcl
set __after  [info procs]
puts "Added procs: [diff $__before $__after]"
```

One thing I like about this solution is that the `diff` procedure is really just a generic set differencing utility -- it's not specific to comparing lists of defined procedures.

Comment: If your system has it, `package require struct::set` and use `struct::set difference` instead of writing your own `diff`. Pro: don't have to write, re-usability. Cons: have to import a bunch on code just to use one function.

Answer (score 1):

The cheapest way is to just open the file and use `regexp` to pick out the names. It's not perfectly accurate, but it does a reasonably good job.

```
set f [open "sourcefile.tcl"]
set data [read $f]
close $f

foreach {dummy procName} [regexp -all -inline -line {^[\s:]*proc (\S+)} $data] {
    puts "Found procedure $procName"
}
```

Does it deal with all cases? No. Does it deal with a useful subset? Yes. Is the subset large enough for you? Quite possibly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, although not that easy. The basic idea is to source the file in a modified slave interp that only executes some commands:

```
proc proc_handler {name arguments body} {
    puts $name
}
set i [interp create -safe]
interp eval $i {proc unknown args {}}
interp alias $i proc {} proc_handler
interp invokehidden source yourfile.tcl
```

This approach will fail if the file requires other packages (`package require` will not work), relies on the result of some usually auto_load'ed commands etc..

It also does not take namespaces into account. (`namespace eval ::foo {proc bar a {}}` creates a proc with the name `::foo::bar`

For a more complex implementation you could look into [auto.tcl](http://core.tcl.tk/tcl/artifact/87760e9173a441ad0c4b77cb9e64355b50f1afcc)'s auto_mkindex, which has a similar goal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach:

1. Create a temporary namespace
2. Source (include) the script in question, then
3. Use the `info procs` command to get a list of procs
4. Delete the temporary namespace upon finish

Here is my script, *list_procs.tcl*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

# Script to scan a Tcl script and list all the procs

proc listProcsFromFile {fileName} {
    namespace eval TempNamespace {
        source $fileName
        set procsList [info procs]
    }
    set result $::TempNamespace::procsList
    namespace delete TempNamespace
    return $result
}

set fileName [lindex $::argv 0]
set procsList [listProcsFromFile $fileName]
puts "File $fileName contains the following procs: $procsList"
```

For example, if you have the following script, *procs.tcl*:

```
proc foo {a b c} {}
proc bar {a} {}
```

Then running the script will produce:

```
$ tclsh list_procs.tcl procs.tcl 
File procs.tcl contains the following procs: foo bar
```

Comment: The use of a child interp is better. Most Tcl files use full qualified names, so they ignore your namespace.